# Localization Problem: Doesn't Display Translated Words

Tags: localization

I'm trying to localize my plugin and with a plugin called CodeStyling Localization, I succeeded to create a .po file. However, the words used in my plugin remain in English although the default language is set to Japanese as defined in wp-configdefine('WPLANG', 'ja');

Other localized plugins are properly translated including, Yet Another Related Posts Plugin and WP Multibyte Patch.

This is a sample plugin I wrote to test plugin localization. I kept it as simple as possible.

**wp-content\plugins\localizationsample\localizationsample.php**

```
<?php
/*  
    Plugin Name: Localization Sample Plugin
    Version: 1.1
    Author: Teno
*/

// Localization
add_action('init', 'localizationsample_init');
function localizationsample_init() {
    $loaded = load_plugin_textdomain('localizationsample', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/lang/');
} 

// Add Admin Menu 
add_action('admin_menu','localizationsample_menu');
function localizationsample_menu() { 
    add_options_page(
        'Localization Sample Plugin',   
        'Localization Sample Plugin',       
        'manage_options',       
        __FILE__,               
        'localizationsample_adminpanel'
    );
}
function localizationsample_adminpanel() {
    echo '<div class="wrap"><div id="icon-themes" class="icon32"></div>';
    echo '<h2>' . __('hi!', 'localizationsample') . '</h2>';    // "hi!" should be translated.
    echo '</div></div>';
}
?>
```

**wp-content\plugins\localizationsample\lang\LSample-ja_JP.po**

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Localization Sample Plugin v1.0\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2012-08-17 20:23+0900\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2012-08-17 11:27:39+0000\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=n != 1;\n"
"X-Poedit-Language: \n"
"X-Poedit-Country: \n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: UTF-8\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: __;_e;__ngettext:1,2;_n:1,2;__ngettext_noop:1,2;_n_noop:1,2;_c,_nc:4c,1,2;_x:1,2c;_ex:1,2c;_nx:4c,1,2;_nx_noop:4c,1,2;\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"X-Poedit-Bookmarks: \n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: Z:/xampp/htdocs/wptest/wp-content/plugins/localizationsample\n"
"X-Textdomain-Support: yes"

#: localizationsample.php:28
#@ LSample
msgid "hi!"
msgstr "やあ！"
```

Both files are saved as UTF-8 without BOM. What am I doing wrong?

*updated the code but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure the language file is found. In your development environment (and only there!) add the following code:

```
$path   = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'lang';
$loaded = load_plugin_textdomain( 'LSample', false, dirname( $path );

if ( ! $loaded )
{
    print "File not found: $path"; 
    exit;
}
```

Then … I would use lowercase text domains only. Not sure if that’s a real issue, but there are some cases where WordPress is setting strings to lowercase automatically. Strings not visible to the end user should stay lowercase.

The `po` file will not be used, you have to create a `mo` file after translation. Make sure to click the button. :)

[image]

Then reload, the strings should be translated now.

Comment: Okey, I created a .mo file as well but it doesn't translate. I also tried lowercase text domain. It did not help either. Also there was an error in my code: add_action('int', 'localizationsample_init'); had to be corrected to add_action('init', 'localizationsample_init');  Also load_plugin_textdomain() does not return a value so checking if it is loaded with your suggested method does not seem to work.

Comment: Was the correct file found? `load_plugin_textdomain()` returns a boolean value.

Comment: load_plugin_textdomain() always seems to return false. According to the documentation of the function, "On failure returns null and also on success returns nothing." Does this mean that if it loads a language file then returns true? "returns nothing" mean returns true, not false?

Comment: Don’t know where you read that. It returns `TRUE` on success and `FALSE` on failure. Look at the source. :)

Comment: Ah, that's for load_textdomain() but the documentation of load_plugin_textdomain() also says "This function does not return a value." http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain

Comment: Again: read the source. Codex is wrong and never reliable. More important: _Test my suggestion._

Comment: I see indeed Codex was wrong. I'm testing with your suggestion now.

Comment: It turned out to be a problem of .mo file naming. CodeStyling Localization created a file named localizationsample-ja_JP.mo but it had to to be localizationsample-ja.mo, without _JP. I realized this by reading the source as you pointed out. It finally got working. Thank you so much.

Comment: Watch out for the file permission as well. If the Web Server can't have access to the file, it will not be able to use it... it sounds silly, but it took me some time to figure out that.

Comment: Problems with translation could come from the filename : if it is a Theme's localisation make sure that it is named "xx_XX.mo", like "de_DE.mo", not "themename_xx_XX.mo". For plugin, it may be "pluginname_xx_XX.mo" (not sure of that). Plugin and theme's localisation can be in different folders, according to the theme's implementation of "load_theme_textdomain" (theme) or "load_plugin_textdomain" (plugin).